# Opening window in new tab returns no errors but also isn't functional

Tags: javascript

This code doesn't open the link despite following the syntax used in every example I can find. What am I doing wrong?

```
<button id="left_button">Button</button>
```

```
left_button.onclick= window.open('www.google.com', '_blank')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onclick` expects a function

```
left_button.onclick = function() { window.open('www.google.com', '_blank') }
```

I'm also assuming `left_button` in your example was the actual element:

```
let left_button = document.getElementById("left_button");
```

Answer (score 0):

when an element has an id, it cannot be accessed in js by simply using its id, instead, you need to do:

```js
document.querySelector("#left_button").onclick= ()=> window.open('www.google.com', '_blank')
```

and make sure the js code is at the end of the body tag or in `head` and use `defer` attribute, or execute your code when the window loads.